# The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library

Tags: maven-2, dependencies, wildcard, springsource, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I use SpringSource Tool Suite 2.3.0. Recently I added the **commons-compress** dependency to pom.xml as required by **jackrabbit 2.0** dependency. Updating maven dependencies console shows:
**"Missing artifact org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.0:compile"**

I checked the Problems view and it shows the following error:

**The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Documents and Settings\AElshereay.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.0\commons-compress-1.0.jar'.**

Also:

**cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'config:simple'.**

I have no idea what is that last! And if it has anything to do to not download the mentioned jar from maven repository even it's there!

Please, can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you found an answer? Would be glad to know how you solved this

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure about the last error message but the two first one are definitely related: you declared a dependency to the POM so the `.classpath` is updated to point on it in your local repository but the file is can't be find in it and Eclipse/STS complains about this.

Now, I tried to declare the commons-compress dependency in a POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And, while I can see some complains about checksum validations:

```
1/23/10 5:11:10 AM CET: Downloading central : org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.0/commons-compress-1.0.pom
1/23/10 5:11:10 AM CET: Downloaded [central] -> http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.0/commons-compress-1.0.pom
1/23/10 5:11:10 AM CET: [WARN] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '325980a09dbbd0c108ece8e7733b462b00e6f2a8'; remote = 'commons-compress-1.0.pom:' - RETRYING
1/23/10 5:11:10 AM CET: Downloading central : org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.0/commons-compress-1.0.pom
1/23/10 5:11:10 AM CET: Downloaded [central] -> http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.0/commons-compress-1.0.pom
1/23/10 5:11:11 AM CET: [WARN] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '325980a09dbbd0c108ece8e7733b462b00e6f2a8'; remote = 'commons-compress-1.0.pom:' - IGNORING
1/23/10 5:11:12 AM CET: Downloading central : org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.0/commons-compress-1.0.jar
1/23/10 5:11:15 AM CET: Downloaded [central] -> http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.0/commons-compress-1.0.jar
1/23/10 5:11:16 AM CET: [WARN] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '995ae384a0b1e2c66269e6bc5198db8561fb45a2'; remote = 'commons-compress-1.0.jar:' - RETRYING
1/23/10 5:11:16 AM CET: Downloading central : org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.0/commons-compress-1.0.jar
1/23/10 5:11:18 AM CET: Downloaded [central] -> http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.0/commons-compress-1.0.jar
1/23/10 5:11:18 AM CET: [WARN] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '995ae384a0b1e2c66269e6bc5198db8561fb45a2'; remote = 'commons-compress-1.0.jar:' - IGNORING
```

The artifacts **gets** downloaded.

So please check that you didn't configure the central repository with a `checksumPolicy`
 set to `fail`. Look for something like that in your [`settings.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-settings/settings.html) or in global settings used by m2eclipse (**Windows > Preferences > Maven > Installations**) or in a project profile:

```
 <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
```

If you can't find anything like that, then a workaround would be to install commons-compress manually.

Comment: Hi Pascal,
Thanks a lot for your response. I checked the settings.xml file and didn't mention checksumPolicy defined!
But I still need to find out what is the actual reason for not downloading the jar before workaround this issue.

Thank you once more.

Comment: @aelshereay As I said, I can't reproduce so I can't really help you further. Maybe try on another machine if you can. This may help you find out if this is a machine specific configuration issue or a more global problem.